# Definition of COBOL variable to use for DB2 date arithmetic

Tags: db2, cobol

I have cases where I want to a add or substract a variable number of days from a timestamp.

The most simple example is this:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - :MOD-DAY DAY
INTO :MYTIMESTAMP        
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

My problem is figuring out the right cobol definition for `MOD-DAY`.
As far as I'm aware, we are running DB2 version 11.

According to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_datearithmetic.html
the DB2 definition of the variable must be `DECIMAL(8,0)`

That could be `9(08)` or `S9(08)` but in both cases, and any other variation I have thought up so far, I get the compile error
`DSNH312I E     DSNHSMUD LINE 1181 COL 49  UNDEFINED OR UNUSABLE HOST VARIABLE "MOD-DAY"`

I have of course made certain that `MOD-DAY` has been defined, so the key word must be `UNUSABLE`

The error code definition for `DSNH312I` is pretty generic:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/msgs/src/tpc/dsnh312i.html

So does anyone know the right COBOL variable definition to use in this case?

Comment: Decimal indicates `comp-3`. Try`s9(08) comp-3`

Comment: Have a look at DB2 dclgens copybooks for DB2 tables/views. They will show both the DB2 definition and how it is converted into Cobol. Find a Decimal field an then look at the Cobol definition

Comment: @BruceMartin: Thank you, that did the trick. Submit it as an answer, and I'll accept it as an answer

Comment: An IBM produced DCLGEN will show S9(8)V USAGE COMP-3.   I'm not sure if the 'V' will matter.

Comment: @JimCastro: `s9(08) comp-3` turned out to be enough, probably since `DECIMAL(8,0)` means nothing after the decimal point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Decimal` in Mainframe-DB2 means **comp-3**.

So the field should be defined as `S9(08) comp-3`

---

If you look at the Cobol Copybooks generated by DB2 for DB2 Tables / Views you will see both the DB2 definition and the generated Cobol fields. That can be another way to solve queries like this